# Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()

Tags: php

i am using sqlite_escape_string($str) to prepare sql statements for future use.

however, when i migrated my code to a new server, it says:

Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()

seems the Sqlite and everything is working in the new server, but i have error even for a sqlite_open().

Anyways, i just need to escape my $str to a sqlite safe sql statments, i dun even need to write to sqlite from PHP, so an

Comment: mind the difference between Sqlite and Sqlite3 extension. You can do php -m from the command line to see all enabled extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ans myself.

It is due to my server is a Centos 5.4, and sqlite support for php is not there.

The same case should exist in REL5 also.

see the 1st and 2nd latest comment in the link below:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php

I solved it by recompiling my php and added the sqlite.ini file

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the SQLite plugin is not enabled for PHP. Write `<?=phpinfo()?>` in a .php file, load it up on your server and see if SQLite is mentioned in the loaded plugins.

Comment: i can see pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x enabled
PECL Module version 1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6 2006/01/01 12:50:12 sniper Exp $
SQLite Library 3.3.6

Comment: Is the phpinfo() in the same file? Check if your script and the test phpinfo() file include the same php.ini settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment the  extension=php_sqlite.dll line by removing the semi colon right now your pdo_sqlite is enabled and sqlite_escape_string is a function of sqlite extension and sqlite_pdo will not work untill php_sqlite is enabled

Comment: No i mean enabled because he could see the pdo extension and since he is using methods of php_sqlite he is getting errors

Answer (score 0):

For those who recently upgraded to 5.4+, note that the php docs say, this method is not available 5.4+

> (PHP 5 < 5.4.0, PECL sqlite >= 1.0.0)

So you would either need to manually compile it in, or look at PECL.